# Subtleties of php GET command

Tags: php

I have a page where I am trying to retrieve a value from the URL bar to then be used as an argument in an sql call.  However I am having some issues.

The url is XXXXXXXXXX.php?mid=314

At the top of my code i have

```
$mid = (int)trim($_GET['mid']," "); // Method A: This version does not work
$mid = 314; // Method B: This version does work


$mission = $db->getTableInfoForMission($mid); 
// This is the sql call that works for Method B and fails for Method A.
```

I have output the value of $mid and it appears to be 314, is there something I am missing?

Thanks

EDIT*

After trying //var_dump($mid); die();  for both cases I get int(314), yet still one method fails and the other does not.  I get an invalid SQL syntax failure for method A

Comment: Try adding print_r($_GET) and print_r($_POST) prior to your first line to get a dump of the two possible sources of URL data.  That might tell you everything you need to know :).

Comment: APPEARS doesn't help much. `var_dump($mid)` will tell you more. if it says anything OTHER than `string(3)`, you've got some invisible characters hiding in there.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what error do you get?

Comment: @R.Barzell even better, use `var_dump()`, which is better at detecting non-string values or extra spaces.

Comment: Also, `var_dump()` the value of `$mid` after it's assigned - that'll isolate the problem and remove the db stuff entirely.

Comment: You really need to add the appropriate error messages (**in full**) and related code sections before anyone can help you

Comment: SO is not the right place for debugging help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your URL is `XXXXXXXXXX.php?mid=314`, then the `mid` index of `$_GET` **will** be set to 314 when calling `XXXXXXXXXX.php`, unless your webserver does something really sneaky...

```
$mid = trim($_GET['mid']); // No need to specify " ", that's natural behaviour.
```

Think about checking the type with `is_integer($mid)`, and make sure absolutely *nothing* interferes with the value of `$mid`. The following debugging calls might also help you :

- `var_dump($mid); die();` - after assigning `$mid`.
- `var_dump($_GET); die();` - at the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `(int)` cast and remove the second argument from the `trim()` function since the `trim()` function removes any spaces by default

```
$mid = trim($_GET['mid']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily an answer to your specific issue but a valuable resource is to look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. This will give you everything after the Top Level Domain and through some string manipulation you can do some very useful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even bother with `trim`. A simple

```
if (!isset($_GET['mid'])) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Required query param "mid" is missing');
}

$mid = (int) $_GET['mid'];
```

should be all you need.

Also make sure you have proper error reporting and display configured in your development environment (`php.ini`)

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```